# Lots of rectangles/sprites causing lag. Need a better way to use them

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a minimap-type thing I am trying to implement in my game. I create the minimap like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
    float tileX = (200 * tilearray.get(i).getX()) / (getmWidth() * 64);
    float tileY = (100 * tilearray.get(i).getY()) / (getmHeight() * 64);
    Sprite tileSprite = new Sprite(tileX+590, tileY+380,  (64 * 200) / (getmWidth() * 64) + (float) 1, (64 * 100)
            / (getmHeight() * 64) + (float) 1, resourcesManager.smallRect_region, vbom);
    tileSprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
    tileSprite.clearEntityModifiers();
    tileSprite.clearUpdateHandlers();
    gameHUD.attachChild(tileSprite);
}
```

And it works fine, but it makes my game choppy and slow. This is understandable because I could be using upwards of 200/300 sprites, but I need a way to create this minimap in the same way, without lag. I've tried:

```
tileSprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
tileSprite.clearEntityModifiers();
tileSprite.clearUpdateHandlers();
```

which I thought would *just* show the image of the sprite and remove almost all functionality behind it, but no. So how can I create the same effect, but in a much more memory-efficient way?

I am on Android, using AndEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on count of tilearray it may be an overkill by GC. Try not create sprites in every iteration but render them only using eg. SpriteBatch or implement pooling by GenericPool.

There are some ways to optimize this even futher, by using custom vertex buffer object  or share vertex buffer object. Also remember to keep sprites in atlases to avoid multiple texture  switches to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many sprites out of camera view, you can use sprite.setCulling() method.